# Render Angular component through wordpress plugin with shortcode

Tags: angular, wordpress

I've written a small wordpress plugin which should render specific components in my website.
I first tried to call directly `<app-searchbox>` but only `<app-root>` seems to work after all. So I tried to differentiate between the components. But the `componentType` is never coming through.

Code in Wordpress:

```
add_shortcode( 'cvz_product_search', 'product_search' );
// main.js, polyfills.js and runtime.js are correctly loaded, plain <app-root></app-root> works

function product_search()
    {
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <app-root [componentType]="searchbox"></app-root>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

Code in my Angular App:

app.component.html:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="componentType">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'searchbox'">
    <app-searchbox></app-searchbox>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'product-search';
  @Input() componentType: string = 'default';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.componentType); // this is always returning "default" and I don't know why....
  }
}
```

Console error in browser:

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002
Error: NG04002
    at Dk.noMatchError (main.js?ver=2.3:1:187137)
    at main.js?ver=2.3:1:187421
    at main.js?ver=2.3:1:151701
    at Hw._error (main.js?ver=2.3:1:8342)
    at Hw.error (main.js?ver=2.3:1:2968)
    at Hw._error (main.js?ver=2.3:1:3208)
    at Hw.error (main.js?ver=2.3:1:2968)
    at Hw._error (main.js?ver=2.3:1:3208)
    at Hw.error (main.js?ver=2.3:1:2968)
    at Hw._error (main.js?ver=2.3:1:3208)
    at z (polyfills.js?ver=2.3:1:16005)
    at z (polyfills.js?ver=2.3:1:15555)
    at polyfills.js?ver=2.3:1:16837
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.js?ver=2.3:1:7208)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js?ver=2.3:1:88939)
    at v.invokeTask (polyfills.js?ver=2.3:1:7129)
    at M.runTask (polyfills.js?ver=2.3:1:2573)
    at _ (polyfills.js?ver=2.3:1:9225)
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Self-answered: There is no (easy?) way to achieve that. I am instead using different apps for each component. Eventually, it's be possible to differentiate by url, but that is a very static solution.